# How to centre child on custom paint in flutter like this image?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

i was trying to make something looks like this [image: image1]
here is my code
 `CustomPaint( painter: HexagonPainter(center: Offset(100, 100), radius: 65), child: Icon(Icons.speed), );`
but I'm getting result like this [image: image 2]
they are not together ..how can I archive this
custom painter code `

```
class HexagonPainter extends CustomPainter {
static const int SIDES_OF_HEXAGON = 6;
 final double? radius;
 final Offset? center;

HexagonPainter({this.center, this.radius});

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
Paint paint = Paint()..color = Color(0xff05c2c9);
 Path path = createHexagonPath();

canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

Path createHexagonPath() {
final path = Path();
var angle = (math.pi * 2) / SIDES_OF_HEXAGON;
Offset firstPoint =
    Offset(radius! * math.cos(0.0), radius! * math.sin(0.0));
path.moveTo(firstPoint.dx + center!.dx, firstPoint.dy + center!.dy);
for (int i = 1; i <= SIDES_OF_HEXAGON; i++) {
  double x = radius! * math.cos(angle * i) + center!.dx;
  double y = radius! * math.sin(angle * i) + center!.dy;
  path.lineTo(x, y);
}

path.close();

return path;
}

@override
bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
```

}
`

Comment: have you tried using stack widget it will easy to do so I guess

Comment: not working..........

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: HexagonPainter(),
              ),
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.speed,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class HexagonPainter extends CustomPainter {
  static const int SIDES_OF_HEXAGON = 6;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()..color = const Color(0xff05c2c9);
    var radius = size.width / 2;

    Path path =
        createHexagonPath(radius, Offset(size.height / 2, size.width / 2));

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  Path createHexagonPath(double radius, Offset center) {
    final path = Path();
    var angle = (math.pi * 2) / SIDES_OF_HEXAGON;
    Offset firstPoint = Offset(radius * math.cos(0.0), radius * math.sin(0.0));
    path.moveTo(firstPoint.dx + center.dx, firstPoint.dy + center.dy);
    for (int i = 1; i <= SIDES_OF_HEXAGON; i++) {
      double x = radius * math.cos(angle * i) + center.dx;
      double y = radius * math.sin(angle * i) + center.dy;
      path.lineTo(x, y);
    }

    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

i have fixed this by using an image instead the paint